# Having an issue decomiling pyc file

Tags: python, pyc

I am trying to decompile a file but I have run into an error.

```
C:\Users\Owner>decompyle3 wvripper.pyc
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\owner\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\runpy.py", line 194, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "c:\users\owner\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Scripts\decompyle3.exe\__main__.py", line 4, in <module>
  File "c:\users\owner\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\decompyle3\__init__.py", line 48, in <module>
    import decompyle3.semantics.pysource
  File "c:\users\owner\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\decompyle3\semantics\pysource.py", line 139, in <module>
    import decompyle3.parsers.main as python_parser
  File "c:\users\owner\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\decompyle3\parsers\__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    from decompyle3.parsers.main import *
  File "c:\users\owner\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\decompyle3\parsers\main.py", line 32, in <module>
    from xdis import iscode, py_str2float
ImportError: cannot import name 'py_str2float' from 'xdis' (c:\users\owner\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\xdis\__init__.py)
```

Apparently, I cannot import a file. What should I do?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I believe `py_str2float` needs to be imported `from xdis.magics` as in this example: https://github.com/welchbj/formatic/blob/524aed11c33627eba51cff169d8210f01660a250/formatic/walkers/code_object_injection_walker.py#L12-L13